# If $\left|z+1\right|=3$, determine the greatest and least possible values for $|z|$

Tags: complex-numbers, maxima-minima, absolute-value, triangle-inequality

If $\left|z+1\right|=3$, determine the greatest and least possible values for $|z|$

According to the answer, the greatest value of $|z|$ is $2$ and the least is $-4$.

But why is that?

My attempt:

if $\left|z+1\right|=3$, then $-(z+1) = 3$ or $(z+1) = 3$

therefore $z = -4$ and $|z| = 4$ and $z = 2$ and $|z| = 2$

which corresponds to the value $4$ to be the greatest and $2$ to be the least. I want to know why this thinking is wrong?

So I googled to find help. I watched this video by Eddie Woo --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3YNDyeiSiY&ab_channel=EddieWoo. The solution is really long and some commenters says that he is wrong.

Comment: If $z=4$ then $|z+1|=5$ not $3$.  And it is easy to confirm that, if $z=-4$ , then $|z+1|=3$ as claimed.

Comment: Do you really believe that $|z|$ can be $-4$?

Comment: $-(z+1) = 3$ means $z = -4$

Comment: You should stop and question whether were were asking for greatest and least values of $z$, or greatest and least values of $|z|$ and recognize the difference between these two questions.  It could be the problem source has a typo, you have a typo, problem source or you have a misunderstanding, or similar...

Comment: note:$|z|\ge 0$ always!

Comment: Sorry everyone ;(

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore correction: $|z|\geq 0$ always.

Comment: @JMoravitz they are asking for $|z|$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for response, can you possibly check whether https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3YNDyeiSiY&ab_channel=EddieWoo is correct?

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks!typo

Comment: It is also worth stopping and checking whether we are talking about real numbers $z$ only or if we allow $z$ to be complex.  You tag this with complex numbers and the linked to a youtube video which clearly is about complex numbers.  You write however that $|z+1|=3$ implies that $(z+1)=3$ or $-(z+1)=3$... That is incorrect for the case of complex numbers.  Those happen to be the only two real values of $z$ such that $|z+1|=3$ however there are infinitely many complex numbers $z$ such that $|z+1|=3$

Answer (score 1):

By the triangle inequality: $$3=|z+1|\geq|z|-1,$$ which gives $$|z|\leq4.$$
The equality occurs for $z=-4$, which says that we got a maximal value.

Also, by the triangle inequality again:
$$3=|z+1|\leq|z|+1,$$ which gives $$|z|\geq2.$$
The equality occurs for $z=2$, which says that we got a minimal value.

Answer (score 0):

|z| can never be a negative value. Thus |z| = -4 can never be a possible solution. Thus your answer seems to be correct if the values for |z| are asked ...

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the problem is mistaken. If it asks for $|z|$, then because the solutions are $-4$ and $2$, the greates solution would be $|-4|=4$

Comment: "*the solutions are $-4$ and $2$*" implying you think there are no other solutions, but it is heavily implied from context that we are meant to consider complex $z$ as well so you are missing talking about the infinitely many other complex $z$ on the circle of radius $3$ centered at $-1$ which satisfy $|z+1|=3$.